# No sound is generated when using PlaySound()

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, playsound

Basically I want to use the [`PlaySound()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680(v=VS.85).aspx) function in ctypes.

> Yes I know winsound module is built on it and I could use that, but I have a reason to not do so :)

---

In C I would call the function like this:

```
PlaySound("sound.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

---

I have my Python script equivalent:

```
import ctypes

winmm = ctypes.WinDLL('winmm.dll')

winmm.PlaySound("sound.wav", None, 0x20000)
```

I run it, no error is returned but the sound does not play either.

---

I suspect that the problem lies with the hex value (`0x20000`) since everything else seems fine.  I got this value like this:

```
import winsound
print(hex(winsound.SND_FILENAME))
```

Or in a different way:

```
import ctypes, winsound

winmm = ctypes.WinDLL('winmm.dll')

winmm.PlaySound("sound.wav", None, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

So how can I get this working so that my file plays?

Comment: Why not try using the [winsound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#module-winsound) module?

Comment: @l'L'l  Looks like I might have made a mistake.  I can't get the mp3 to play in C now either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, there are Unicode and ANSI versions of functions.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680(v=VS.85).aspx) indicates the filename is an `LPCTSTR`.  For the ANSI version that is defined as `LPCSTR` and for Unicode it is `LPCWSTR`.

Here's the proper way to call a Windows function.  Generally you want the `W` version of the function.  Defining `.argtypes` and `.restype` will also help with error checking.  As you found, you can pass the wrong type and it will not work.  With `.argtypes` defined, incompatible types will be caught.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

dll = WinDLL('winmm')

dll.PlaySoundW.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR,w.HMODULE,w.DWORD
dll.PlaySoundW.restype = w.BOOL

SND_FILENAME = 0x20000

# Call it with a Unicode string and it works.
dll.PlaySoundW('sound.wav',None,SND_FILENAME)

# Call it with a byte string and get an error since `.argtypes` is defined.
dll.PlaySoundW(b'sound.wav',None,SND_FILENAME)
```

Output (after sound plays):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    dll.PlaySoundW(b'sound.wav',None,SND_FILENAME)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Or skip all that work and just use the winsound module:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680(v=VS.85).aspx) specifying it as a string.

> A string that specifies the sound to play

In Python you actually have to make it byte values.  So simply:

```
winmm.PlaySound(b"sound.wav", None, 0x20000)
```